# Node: spawn a command and print results to a file

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

If I want to list the files of a directory and save the results in a `res.txt` I can run the command

`ls -l > res.txt`

Now I would like to do the same in a process spawned from the main process of Node.

I have tried naively this

```
spawn(
  'ls',
  ['-l', '>', 'res.txt'],
);
```

but does not work. Is there any way to achieve what i want?

Comment: do you really want to spawn a process, or just get a list of files, inside node?

Comment: I really want to spawn a process

Answer (score 0):

After some more googling I found that the `shell: true` option does the trick.

So, if I want a spawned process to run a command which streams its output to a file, I can use this approach

```
spawn(
  'ls -l > res.txt',
  [],
  {shell: true}
);
```

Answer (score -1):

so from the node documentation, which can be found here:

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked. This command is to execute a child process and that's it.